# How to mount PVC on pod in OpenShift Online 3

Tags: amazon-ec2, openshift

I just ported my application to OpenShift Online 3 (from version 2), and now I'm struggling to understand how to manage persistent, "shared" data, that is not wiped after each build.

After reading the documentation about Persistent Volume Claims, I created a new PVC inside my project, of type RWO, using the Web dashboard. At this point I tried to understand how to access this storage from inside each pod, or if I needed to do something to mount it, and I ended up doing this:

```
$ oc volume dc/myapp --add --type=persistentVolumeClaim --claim-name=pvcname --mount-path=/usr/share/data
```

After this, it looks like the new configuration was successfully registered:

```
$ oc volume dc --all
deploymentconfigs/myapp
  pvc/pvcname (allocated 1GiB) as volume-jh1jf
    mounted at /usr/share/data
```

I could also see the new `/usr/share/data` directory from inside the pods created by the new builds.

However, after making this change, all deployments started failing with this error:

> Failed to attach volume "pvc-0b747c80-a687-11e7-9eb0-122631632f42" on node "ip-172-31-48-134.ec2.internal" with: Error attaching EBS volume "vol-0008c8127ff0f4617" to instance "i-00195cc4e1d31f8ce": VolumeInUse: vol-0008c8127ff0f4617 is already attached to an instance status code: 400, request id: 722f3797-f486-4739-ab4e-fe1826ae53af. The volume is currently attached to instance "i-089e2a60e525f447c"

from which it looks like my latest change had the effect of attaching the volume to a specific instance. But then how can I mount the volume to my pods so that it survives each build and deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using an EBS volume type, you must set the deployment strategy on the deployment config to `Recreate` instead of `Rolling`. This is because an EBS volume can only be mounted on a single node in the cluster at a time. This means you cannot using a rolling deployment, nor scale your application above 1 replica, as both result in more than one instance and there is no guarantee they will be deployed to the same node.